# Field is required. even after filling the field - Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am following this course, and the instructor added code to add records to the DB. The class that's going to be added to the DB looks like this:

```
  public class Gig
   {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Artist { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ArtistId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Venue { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte GenreId { get; set; }
}
```

And there's a view model that's attached to the view, to do the mapping, and it looks like this:

```
 public class GigFormViewModel
  {

    [Required]
    public string Venue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [FutureDate]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ValidTime]
    public string Time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public DateTime GetDateTime() => DateTime.Parse($"{Date} {Time}"); 
}
```

I have a create method, that gets form fields, and does the mapping from view model to the model itself, and then tries to add the records to the DB, my create action looks like this:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Create(GigFormViewModel viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.Genres = _context.Genres.ToList();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        var gig = new Gig()
        {

            GenreId = viewModel.Genre, 
            ArtistId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),   
            DateTime = viewModel.GetDateTime(),
            Venue = viewModel.Venue
        };

        _context.Gigs.Add(gig);
        _context.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

On the submit, I get the viewModel's property `Genres` and populate it with the records from the DB, then I check for `ModelState.IsValid`. but it's giving me:

> Genres Field is required

Although I set it just 2 lines above.

Is there something wrong am doing here? Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add a validation data annotation to `Genres` property in your view model because it is not a data that is set by users but it is set by you to help your view to get a collection of `Genre` and populate something like a dropdown list.

Firstly, remove the `[Required]` attribute that decorates your `Genres` property in `GigFormViewModel`.
Secondly, refactor your action method, specially the `if` bloc like below:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(GigFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // re-populate Genres collection only is tha data is in invalid state.
        viewModel.Genres = _context.Genres.ToList();
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // The remainder code does not change
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: One more thing, when I tried to save my form, I got an error for DateTime.Parse($"{Date} {Time}") .. that it's not in a correct format, where the data is: "18/11/2017" and time is "2:35" .. can you tell me what's wrong with this? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't vote the answer up, don't have enough reputation to do so :(

Comment: It seems like you're using datetime in French format if so then you need to pass the format provider as a second parameter of Parse method. You can pass new CultureInfo("fr-fr") if you think you will only work with french culture.

Comment: For best answer about that create another thread because this thread is solved.